# How to debug HTTP connections from my local PHP server

Tags: php, curl, yii2

I'm new to PHP development and came from HTML5 / javascript dev where I obviously use Chrome dev tools network tab for convenient debugging of all network connections my apps do. Now, I have a PHP app that makes requests to different APIs on Internet and I faced a huge problem debugging these HTTP connections. I use methods described here: http://blog.kettle.io/debugging-curl-requests-in-php. But, sure, it's not that convenient as in Chrome web tools, where I can see a payload, response and other data in nicely structured way. My config is OS X 10.10 and MAMP. The app is based on Yii2 framework (this is probably redundant info, but just in case) and currently it's installed locally. Please advise on what are the best tools for debugging HTTP connections my local PHP app do outside.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/debugging-a-php-http-request.html

Answer (score 1):

There are several quite different ways of doing it:

1. Add logging to your CURL methods. In common way it will look like

`$result = $this->execCurl($url, $method, $params); 
Yii::info('External API Called. Request: '.$url.' Response: '.implode(',', $result));`

After this you can find in your runtime directory app.log where you will see the result. For more information read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-logger.html

2. Use special network traffic capturing software, f.e. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
   It allows you to capture all requests from your PC to any remote host, or to any local services aswell. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for your response! With regards to the option 2: I can not use Fiddler, since I'm on mac, what's a good alternative to Fiddler for OS X?

Comment: There is Fiddler alpha realese for Mac based on Mono framework. The WinForms framework on Mac is almost unusably buggy. Your best bet is to run Fiddler inside a Linux or Windows Virtual Machine and point the Mac's proxy settings at that. You can see more here http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono Since i'm not developing on mac, probably it's better to wait competent anwer from mac users.